# Meaning of exponent in logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

I have this particular difficulty : $$\log_b^a(c)=x$$
I know it is different from power of base $\log_{b^a}(c)=x$, but what does it actually mean?

**The actual question** that i got in paper was
    Find value of $$\sqrt{\log_{0.5}^2 8}$$
And its answer was given as $3$.

Comment: Where did you encounter this?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't just mean $(\log_b(c))^a$?  Like we write $\cos^a(x)$ for $(\cos x)^a$.

Comment: I got an assignment from school, in that.

Comment: I don't think people usually do this.

Comment: With the elementary functions like $\sin$, $\cos$, $\log$, people write $\log_b^a(x)$ to mean $(\log_b(x))^a$. This notation is used to economize the space from the parentheses and to avoid the confusion with $\log_b(x)^a$ and $\log_b(x^a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponent is a power, so you should read $\log_b^a(c)=x$ as $(\log_b(c))^a=x$ In your specific case, $\log_{0.5}8=-3$, so when you square that you get $9$ and when you take the square root you get get $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Well that pretty much means $$(\log_{b}(c))^a$$ In you case, it simplifies to $$\sqrt{(\log_{0.5}{8})^2} = |\log_{0.5}{8}| = |-3| = 3$$